# Захват входящего номера

Tags: java, android

Есть ли возможность на Android 4.0.0+ "подписаться" на события входящего звонка и получить номер звонящего. После этого произвести какие-нибудь вычисления (например, сходить в БД), и вывести на экране сообщение (нотификацию)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно зарегистрировать `BroadcastReceiver` в `AndroidMainifest.xml`:

```
<receiver android:name=".PhoneStateReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Запросить разрешение с помощью `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>`. В случае с *Android 6.0 (API level 23)*  необходимо будет запросить данный *permission*  в *runtime*.

Код `PhoneStateReeceiver.java` должен выглядеть так:

```
 public class PhoneStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            try {
                String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
                String incomingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
                if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)){
                    Toast.makeText(context,"Входящий звонок от " + incomingNumber, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

Что должно быть в Main?
(I'm just starting work with android studio)

Thanks)